# No transaction is in progress after spring boot upgrade to 2.6.2

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

Upgraded the spring boot from 2.1.2.RELEASE  to 2.6.2. Upgraded hibernate and hazelcast also as per spring boot doc.
This is working properly in 2.1.2.RELEASE
But unable to start the application. Getting below error

```
/\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.2)

Spring Boot version 2.6.2


2022-03-24 16:23:24.356 INFO  [main] org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser(:469) - Properties location [file:${CACHE_CONFIG}] not resolvable: Could not resolve placeholder 'CACHE_CONFIG' in value "file:${CACHE_CONFIG}"
2022-03-24 16:23:26.222 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate(:132) - Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-03-24 16:23:26.632 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate(:201) - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 378 ms. Found 9 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-03-24 16:23:33.400 INFO  [main] org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean(:437) - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-03-24 16:23:33.585 INFO  [main] org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.MultiTenantKeycloakConfiguration(:31) - setting keycloakproperties to multitenant keycloak config resolver
2022-03-24 16:23:34.253 WARN  [main] io.undertow.websockets.jsr(:68) - UT026010: Buffer pool was not set on WebSocketDeploymentInfo, the default pool will be used
2022-03-24 16:23:34.327 INFO  [main] org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext(:290) - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 10810 ms
2022-03-24 16:23:35.151 INFO  [main] org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.RegistrationBean(:50) - Filter keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter was not registered (disabled)
2022-03-24 16:23:35.153 INFO  [main] org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.RegistrationBean(:50) - Filter keycloakPreAuthActionsFilter was not registered (disabled)
2022-03-24 16:23:35.604 INFO  [main] com.XXXX.smp.distributed.cache.hazelcast.HazelCastSpringConfig(:157) - Hazelcast started with database discovery mode.
2022-03-24 16:23:35.746 INFO  [main] com.XXXX.smp.distributed.cache.hazelcast.HazelCastSpringConfig(:104) - Default Configuration for hazelcast loaded
2022-03-24 16:23:35.761 INFO  [main] com.XXXX.smp.distributed.cache.hazelcast.HazelCastSpringConfig(:121) - Configuring cache :CacheProperties [name=PortalAssetLock, idleTimeoutMilliSeconds=600000, maxTimeoutMilliSeconds=-1]
2022-03-24 16:23:35.801 INFO  [main] com.XXXX.smp.distributed.cache.hazelcast.HazelCastSpringConfig(:121) - Configuring cache :CacheProperties [name=notification_cache, idleTimeoutMilliSeconds=-1, maxTimeoutMilliSeconds=60000]
2022-03-24 16:23:35.836 WARN  [main] com.hazelcast.instance.impl.HazelcastInstanceFactory(:56) - Hazelcast is starting in a Java modular environment (Java 9 and newer) but without proper access to required Java packages. Use additional Java arguments to provide Hazelcast access to Java internal API. The internal API access is used to get the best performance results. Arguments to be used:
 --add-modules java.se --add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED
2022-03-24 16:23:37.032 INFO  [main] com.hazelcast.system(:56) - [10.139.221.242]:5702 [TestHazelcast] [4.2.4] Hazelcast 4.2.4 (20211220 - 25f0049) starting at [10.139.221.242]:5702
2022-03-24 16:23:37.864 INFO  [main] com.hazelcast.instance.impl.Node(:56) - [10.139.221.242]:5702 [TestHazelcast] [4.2.4] Using Discovery SPI
2022-03-24 16:23:37.883 WARN  [main] com.hazelcast.cp.CPSubsystem(:56) - [10.139.221.242]:5702 [TestHazelcast] [4.2.4] CP Subsystem is not enabled. CP data structures will operate in UNSAFE mode! Please note that UNSAFE mode will not provide strong consistency guarantees.
2022-03-24 16:23:38.502 INFO  [main] com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.Diagnostics(:56) - [10.139.221.242]:5702 [TestHazelcast] [4.2.4] Diagnostics disabled. To enable add -Dhazelcast.diagnostics.enabled=true to the JVM arguments.
2022-03-24 16:23:38.527 INFO  [main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService(:56) - [10.139.221.242]:5702 [TestHazelcast] [4.2.4] [10.139.221.242]:5702 is STARTING

2022-03-24 16:23:39.115 ERROR [main] com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.DiscoveryJoiner(:56) - [10.139.221.242]:5702 [TestHazelcast] [4.2.4] no transaction is in progress
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:445) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar!/:5.6.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(SessionImpl.java:3478) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar!/:5.6.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1394) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar!/:5.6.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1389) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar!/:5.6.3.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.flush(SessionFactoryUtils.java:113) ~[spring-orm-5.3.14.jar!/:5.3.14]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionSynchronization.beforeCommit(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:95) ~[spring-orm-5.3.14.jar!/:5.3.14]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:97) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar!/:5.3.14]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:916) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar!/:5.3.14]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:727) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar!/:5.3.14]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar!/:5.3.14]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar!/:5.3.14]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar!/:5.3.14]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar!/:5.3.14]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar!/:5.3.14]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar!/:5.3.14]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar!/:5.3.14]
        at com.XXXX.smp.distributed.cache.db.HazelCastPingDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9aba005f.getMembers(<generated>) ~[HazelCastAdapter-220.0.0.0-20220322.230530-30.jar!/:?]
        at com.XXXX.smp.distributed.cache.hazelcast.HazelcastDatabaseDiscoveryStrategy.discoverNodes(HazelcastDatabaseDiscoveryStrategy.java:36) ~[HazelCastAdapter-220.0.0.0-20220322.230530-30.jar!/:?]
        at com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.impl.DefaultDiscoveryService.discoverNodes(DefaultDiscoveryService.java:72) ~[hazelcast-4.2.4.jar!/:4.2.4]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.DiscoveryJoiner.getPossibleAddresses(DiscoveryJoiner.java:71) ~[hazelcast-4.2.4.jar!/:4.2.4]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.DiscoveryJoiner.getPossibleAddressesForInitialJoin(DiscoveryJoiner.java:60) ~[hazelcast-4.2.4.jar!/:4.2.4]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner.joinViaPossibleMembers(TcpIpJoiner.java:136) ~[hazelcast-4.2.4.jar!/:4.2.4]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner.doJoin(TcpIpJoiner.java:96) ~[hazelcast-4.2.4.jar!/:4.2.4]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.AbstractJoiner.join(AbstractJoiner.java:137) ~[hazelcast-4.2.4.jar!/:4.2.4]
        at com.hazelcast.instance.impl.Node.join(Node.java:810) ~[hazelcast-4.2.4.jar!/:4.2.4]
        at com.hazelcast.instance.impl.Node.start(Node.java:473) ~[hazelcast-4.2.4.jar!/:4.2.4]
        at com.hazelcast.instance.impl.HazelcastInstanceImpl.<init>(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:123) ~[hazelcast-4.2.4.jar!/:4.2.4]
        at com.hazelcast.instance.impl.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:211) ~[hazelcast-4.2.4.jar!/:4.2.4]
        at com.hazelcast.instance.impl.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:190) ~[hazelcast-4.2.4.jar!/:4.2.4]
        at com.hazelcast.instance.impl.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:128) ~[hazelcast-4.2.4.jar!/:4.2.4]
        at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:57) ~[hazelcast-4.2.4.jar!/:4.2.4]
```

HazelCastSpringConfig File

```
@Bean
    public HazelcastInstance hazelCastInstance() {
        Config config = config();
        config.setClusterName("TestHazelcast");
        :
        :
        HazelcastInstance hzInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
         return hzInstance;
    }
```

TestApplication

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

DatabaseConfiguration File

```
@ConditionalOnProperty("spring.datasource.url")
@Configuration("databaseConfiguration")
public class DatabaseConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;


    @PostConstruct
    public void initSessionFactory() {
        SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactoryImpl.class);
        EventListenerRegistry registry = sessionFactory.getServiceRegistry()
            .getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.PERSIST).prependListener(new EntityListener());
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.SAVE).prependListener(new EntityListener());
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.SAVE_UPDATE)
                .prependListener(new EntityListener());
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.PERSIST_ONFLUSH)
                .prependListener(new EntityListener());
        ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory =
                ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) context).getBeanFactory();
        beanFactory.registerSingleton("sessionFactory",
                sessionFactory);
    }
}
```

Application properties file

```
spring.datasource.url=${datasource_url:jdbc:h2:mem:bot;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=MySQL}
spring.datasource.username=${datasource_username:sa}
spring.datasource.password =${datasource_password:sa}
spring.datasource.driver-class=${datasource_driver_class:org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect}
spring.jpa.show-sql=${jpa_show_sql:false}

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false


spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=${datasource_idle_timeout:20000}
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=${datasource_max_lifetime:30000}
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=${datasource_max_connection_timeout:60000}

server.port=${server_port:6080}
server.servlet.context-path=/
server.max-http-header-size=1MB

hazelcast_server_bind_group=PortalHazelcast
hibernate.allow_update_outside_transaction = true
```

Could some help me to resolve this issue. I am stuck with this more than 1 week.

Thanks in adavance.

Comment: _hazelcast-hibernate53 supports Hibernate 5.3.x/5.4.x, and Hazelcast 4+_ . I see you use Hibernate 5.6.x which is not in the list

Comment: @NicoVanBelle Thx for your reply. I tried with  5.4.33.Final  same issue                    javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:422) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.33.Final.jar:5.4.33.Final]

Comment: @Poornima Any update on this issue?
Im also facing this issue.

Comment: Same issue with Spring Boot 2.7.5 and Hibernate 5.6

Comment: @RobertoRodriguez did you get some solution? Facing similar issue.

Comment: @RimjhimDoshi I added the solution that worked for me below.

Answer (score 0):

Need to define the **transactionManager** bean, see example below is working for me:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DelegatingDataSource; 
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;

/**
 *
 * @author rrodriguez
 */ 
public abstract class BasePersistenceConfig {

    protected abstract String[] getMappingResources();

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() throws Exception {
       //implementation here
    }
 
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() throws Exception {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        sessionFactoryBean.setMappingResources(getMappingResources());

        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(
            SessionFactory sessionFactory) { 
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
    }

    Properties hibernateProperties() {
        return new Properties() {
            {
                setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
                setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"); 
            }
        };
    }

}
```